# picture should load fast, change resolution?

Tags: html, css

How can i minimize the loadingtime of images? As example i have 20x the same image on my frontpage (size 1920x1080)

here the image

[image]

Now I want crop the image on a fixed size. For this I use this css code

```css
.startpage_image_container{
 max-width: 100px;
 max-height: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image{
 object-fit: cover;
 object-position: center center;
 height: 200px;
 width: 100px;
}

.section{
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="startpage_image_container">
  <img class="image" src="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2013/03/28/65631/big_thumb_3c7c52cc466a1c188ced0ff17d2ea558.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

But the loadingtime is still very high. How can i minimize the images with PHP and reduce the loading time? And how can i reload content on a page, after the user scrolled at the bottom of the page?

Comment: It doesn't take `long` to load the images/page here.

Comment: You should be careful of using `object-fit`... it has very limited support (no IE support at all) See [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

Comment: You may want to look into lazy loading. There are several javascript plugins for this out there. Like this [one](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/)

Comment: @zgood do you know a alternative to `object-fit`?

Comment: @Name Usually to achieve something similar I would replace the `img` with a `div`, give it a height and width you want, then set `background-size: cover;` and set an inline style on the div of `background: url(...) no-repeat;` as you iterate over your list of images.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
<?php
 echo "<script>
      // http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/
      function preloader() {
        if (document.getElementById) {
          document.getElementById(\"preload-01\").style.background = \"url('img/bg-contact.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-02\").style.background = \"url('img/bg-faq.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-03\").style.background = \"url('img/bg-index.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-04\").style.background = \"url('img/bg-product.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-05\").style.background = \"url('img/callout-money.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-06\").style.background = \"url('img/callout-question-mark.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-07\").style.background = \"url('img/callout-wow.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-08\").style.background = \"url('img/featured.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-09\").style.background = \"url('img/footer-vlad.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
          document.getElementById(\"preload-10\").style.background = \"url('img/vlad.png') no-repeat -9999px -9999px\";
      }
      function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
          window.onload = func;
        } else {
          window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
              oldonload();
            }
            func();
          }
        }
      }
      addLoadEvent(preloader);
      // End pre-loader functions
    </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is the script exactly doing? Reloading the images?

Comment: The script makes an HTTP request for the image.  Once the image is loaded by your browser, the next time the DOM references it, it will use the image it has already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why is there so many images? Use one :) Doing resizing in PHP is a bit difficult as there is no way to get the browsers height and width. Using javascript you can get the browser's resolution and make the image fit that size before it loads. I build a quick plugin that you could work with. It uses the attribute srcset which I don't think current works?

https://github.com/sourRaspberri/srcset-jQuery-plugin/blob/master/main.js

The plugin 'basically' gets different resolutions of the images and find the best fitting size. It's probably not the best method though.

Another idea, if the problem is with the amount of images you're loading. Try using javascript to copy the image rather than writing it in HTML several times.